# Domains and custom DNS server

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, webserver

I recently purchased a VPS plan and a domain. I have a webserver configured on my vps and I've created the necessary directories and configuration for the new domain. I have no idea how to link the Domain to my VPS, since the panel for the domain only accepts an address in the NS1.example.com and I cant set the IP address of my VPS.

Comment: Who did you purchase the domain from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your DNS hosted somewhere.  You could put the DNS on your VPS (install ISC BIND - harder), or use someone else's service (easier).  Some web hosting ISPs offer it for free (such as Godaddy).  I use FreeDns.

http://freedns.afraid.org.